# Change Facebook background of box count

Tags: facebook

In these days Facebook have a transparent background when I have a box-count option on like button. I want to change the background color of box with number of likes.

[Facebook box-count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GbLs.jpg)

Comment: You can’t. The social plugins run inside iframes with content loaded from the Facebook domain, so you have no access to it via JavaScript, and can not influence it with your site’s CSS either. You can of course file a bug report, if you think the plugin itself should behave differently, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can change it with CSS. I had this same problem, I fixed it with the following code:

```
.fb-like{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The background color change is obvious, but you need to change the border radius as well otherwise you see the white background around the like button since it has a 5px border radius.

One thing to note, this code won't do you very well if you include a share button, because there will be a white background between the share button and the like button, and it doesn't look very well, but I nixed the share button and this worked well for me.

Now I just wish I knew how to change the background color in a way that is friendly with the share button so I can add that back. Please let me know if you figure out a way, but for now I'll just submit a bug report to facebook.

**Please note** This is a fix if you use the javascript SDK button. I don't know if it will work with the iframe like button

**Edit:** I have found a more efficient way. This way also only applies to the javascript sdk button. The allowTransparency property of the iframe seems to be bugged for the time being.

If using the javascript SDK button, add this line to the end of the `fb-like` div: 
`data-colorscheme:"dark"`

When doing it this way, it keeps the background transparent unforunately but it changes the text and border to white for better readability and no need to use css overrides. Also when doing it this way you can keep the share button included and it still looks nice.

If doing it this way doesn't suit you, then you are better off just using the button_count layout instead until they fix the transparency property.